# NAnt IF task doesn't seem to work

Tags: nant

I'm trying the example from the NAnt documentation for the **if** task at:

**http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/if.html**

Specifically the following code...

```
<if test="${build.configuration='release'}">
    <echo>Build release configuration</echo>
</if>
```

where build.configuration has been defined beforehand as

```
<property name="build.configuration" value="debug" overwrite="false" />
```

When I run it using **nant.exe (version 0.91.3881.0)**, I get the following error:

```
'}' expected
Expression: ${build.configuration='release'}
                                 ^
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double the `=` symbol as per your web page.

When programming, `=` is an assignment operator in most languages, whereas `==` is the boolean comparison operator.

Comment: That was it.  I know that I tried using the == since I assumed that was the problem as well, but I'm guessing that I must have changed that alongside some other changes I was trying out.  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the NAnt reference should be changed then....

```
<if test="${build.configuration='release'}">
    <echo>Build release configuration</echo>
</if>
```

[See the manual](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/if.html).